# Call an app in a loop with different parameters in Cytoscape

Tags: while-loop, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I'm new in Cytoscape. I want to know how can I run an app (for example MCL clustering algorithm) multiple times with different parameters in Cytoscape. Is there any way to write an script to do that instead of running manually multiple times for different parameters?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Scooter.
I saw his answer.
Still I have problem with MCODE.
I figured it out by reading this paper "Cytoscape Automation: empowering workflow-based network analysis".
I want to put the script here in the case that maybe somebody has question.
From python you need to import

```
import requests, json
import numpy

REST_ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:1234'
```

and then let's say we want to use affinity propagation clustering algorithm, then you can go to help->Automation->CyRest command API. Here you can find the app and all its parameters. You load the input network from cytoscape in the beginning.

```
counter = 0
ap_clusters = dict()
for i in numpy.arange(-1.0, 1.1, 0.1):
    message_body = {
        "preference": str(round(i,1))
        }
    response = requests.post(REST_ENDPOINT + '/v1/commands/cluster/ap', data = 
    json.dumps(message_body), headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    response_data = response.json()['data']
    ap_clusters[counter] = response_data['clusters']
    counter += 1
```

above is a code to call AP clustering multiple times from python.

For AP and MCL the code works for multiple parameters. However when I tried to call MCODE with different set of parameters, it stopped the connection and closed the cytoscape app. It can only run for on set of parameters.
This is the error:
" raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))"

here is the code for mcode algorithm:

```
counter = 0
mcode_clusters = dict()
for i in numpy.arange(3,6,1):
    for j in numpy.arange(0.1,0.56,0.05): #----vertex weight percentage
        for h in ["on","off"]:
            for f in ["on","off"]:
                if f=="on":
                    for p in [0,0.1,0.2]: #---fluffing percentage

                        message_body = {
                                "fluff" : f,
                                "fluffNodeDensityCutoff" : str(round(p,1)),
                                "haircut" : h,
                                "maxDepthFromStart" : str(i),
                                "nodeScoreCutoff": str(round(j,1))
                                }
                        response = requests.post(REST_ENDPOINT + '/v1/commands/cluster/mcode', data = json.dumps(message_body), headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
                        response_data = response.json()['data']
                        mcode_clusters[counter] = response_data['clusters']
                        counter += 1
```

If you have any solutions I really appreciate it if you could share it with me.

Thanks.
SaRa

Answer (score 1):

I think this was answered by Ruth pretty clearly in cytoscape-helpdesk:

> You can do all of the above.  Whatever is easiest for you. 
>   There is a library py2cytoscape that you can use to issue commands to cytoscape from > python.  Info can be found here: https://py2cytoscape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
>   for more info on automation in cytoscape check out: http://manual.cytoscape.org/en/stable/Programmatic_Access_to_Cytoscape_Features_Scripting.html
>
> But you can also run it through automation.  You can create a text file with each of > your commands (for example a list of commands like: cluster mcl attribute="correlation" network=1234") and then go to Tools --> execute batch file to > execute the whole file.  I am not sure if support loops.   If you want to loop through anything I would recommend using python.
>
> Thanks, 
>   Ruth

I'll just add that currently, looping isn't supported in batch files.

-- scooter

Answer (score 0):

In regard to my problem, I have to say that:

There are two mcode in cytoscape. One is in clusterMaker and the other belongs to cytoscape. When I tried to call mcode, I used the command "'/v1/commands/cluster/mcode'" I called the one in clusterMaker however the parameters' name was based on the one in cytoscape. I changed the command to "'/v1/commands/mcode/cluster'" and the the problem is solved now.
Many thanks.
SaRa